# How to use nDPI as iptables module (like ipp2p) to block P2P

Tags: iptables

Since ipp2p hasn't been updated in 6 years and OpenDPI is no longer freely available (except within paid software from ipoque.com), it seems that nDPI from [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ndpi/) is the only current DPI library available.

I need to block p2p and in the past was able to compile ipp2p into a kernal module and implement it using iptables. Does anyone know if its possible to use nDPI to filter p2p using iptables and if so, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab [OpenDPI](https://github.com/thomasbhatia/OpenDPI.git) and [opendpi-netfilter](https://github.com/thomasbhatia/opendpi-netfilter.git). It works on Debian 6 out of the box without a recompile. I'm looking to update netfilter to work with nDPI but will take some time.

Also here's a gist I found for QoS using OpenDPI and netfilter wrapper https:// gist.github.com/3161018.

Comment: We run CentOS and with some small mods we can compile the module but it wont load. Have you ever got it working on CentOS?

Comment: No, never got it to work on CentOS.

Comment: Did you try and fail or never tried? Also, I'd be very interested in your opinion on how much better OpenDPI is than ipp2p at classifying P2P. Obviously encryption evades both of them but is OpenDPI significantly better?